# How do I make my .jar executable?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I built a .jar from an artifact in IntelliJ 14.03.
When I try to open it in the JRE nothing happens.
It's just a simple gui.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Run command at the **jar** location like

```
java -jar <yourJarName>.jar
```

If get any exception at first be sure Java is set at your `PATH` environment variables.

Comment: @user3857111What is the output? what is your operation system?

Comment: Ok I fixed it. My source code was incomplete. That's why the window would not be created.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your application [Entry Point in your manifest file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). Like below.

> We first create a text file named Manifest.txt with the following
>   contents:
>
> Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass